# "Outer" and "inner" things in css positioning (box model)

Tags: css

I was studying displacement properties on MDN and read this (in [top property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top))

> When position is set to absolute or fixed, the top property specifies the distance between the element's outer margin of top edge and the inner border of the top edge of its containing block.

[Another place where the term "inner border edge" appears](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#scrollbar-gutter-property):

> The space between the inner border edge and the outer padding edge which user agents may reserve to display the scrollbar is called the scrollbar gutter.

What does "outer" in "outer margin" and "inner" in "inner border" mean here?

It has something to do with ["outer edge"](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-box-3/#outer-edge) and ["inner edge"](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-box-3/#inner-edge), defined in *CSS Box Model Module Level 3*?

What would be the "inner border" and "outer margin" down here in the image?
[image]

Comment: "outer margin of top edge" => the top outer edge. "inner border of the top edge" => the top padding edge.

Comment: What if the containing block is established by the content edges? In this case, would it be the padding edges of the content edges?

Comment: That contradicts your question. If the positioned box is absolute or fixed, then its containing block is not established by the content edges of an ancestor box.

Comment: in this case the containing block would be the padding edges?

Comment: but why the inner border of the top edge is the padding edge?

Comment: In the case of a `position:absolute` box which has an ancestor box which establishes a [positioned ancestor containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#absolute-positioning-containing-block) (historically this was a non-statically positioned element but there are other properties that can do it too), the containing block is the padding edge of that ancestor element. If there is no such ancestor, then the containing block is the initial containing block, which is a rectangle not derived from the box model.

Comment: The situation is analogous with `position:fixed`. An ancestor element can establish a [fixed positioning containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#fixed-positioning-containing-block), and this uses the padding edge, but if there is no such ancestor then the containing block is the viewport, which again is a rectangle not derived from the box box model.

Comment: More precisely, the padding edge is used if the establishing box is not a `display:inline` box. For inline boxes, there's some special rules because inline boxes can be fragmented over several lines.

Comment: I don't know why MDN uses the phrase "inner border of the top edge". I think most people would understand what it means and that it is coincident with the padding edge, but it is not a phrase that appears in the specifications to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: I found in https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow. "In the case of a scrollbar being placed on an edge of the element's box, it should be inserted between the inner border edge and the outer padding edge [...]"

Comment: So the distance specified by `top` is this? https://imgur.com/a/saSgiwv

Comment: Good find. No, your image is not correct because you've got the padding and border edges the wrong way round.

Comment: truth. would this be then? https://imgur.com/a/6HsBdhH

Comment: Nearly. This: https://imgur.com/a/FswpBfR

Answer (score 0):

Let's see a `top` of 0 percent:

```css
body {
  background: beige;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  right: 40%;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 15%;
  background: gold;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div>The size of this content is determined by the position of its edges.</div>
```

And now let's see a `top` of 10%:

```css
body {
  background: beige;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 40%;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 15%;
  background: gold;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div>The size of this content is determined by the position of its edges.</div>
```

Let's add a `margin-top` and a `padding-top`:

```css
body {
  background: beige;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  right: 40%;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 15%;
  background: gold;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div>The size of this content is determined by the position of its edges.</div>
```

As we can see from the example, in this case `top` means the distance from the edge, so, if you define a margin-top, it will push the item further down.

```css
#first, #second {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}

#second {
    border: 30px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="first"></div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="second"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, but what would the "inner border" and "outer margin" be in the box model above (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAzFm.png)?

Comment: @CristianoMoraes the inner border should be the black border and the outer margin should be the white margin at the outermost of the border.

Comment: But isn't the `border` property already considered the inner part of the box and wouldn't the margin also be considered the outer part? So what would be the outer `border` and the inner margin? What is the meaning of "outer" and "inner" here?

Comment: @CristianoMoraes The inner border is the section between the frontier of the item and its contents. The outer border is the section between the frontier of the item and its outer context in its container. The outer margin is the `margin` and the inner margin is the `padding`.

Comment: would the outer border be the margin?

Comment: @CristianoMoraes the outer border is the section defined by the `border` property. It is the item's attribute, which might be misleading, but it adds space to it's outer region.

Comment: @CristianoMoraes Added a new snippet to my answer that shows that if there are identical divs, except for the fact that the second has a border, it moves the second from the edge by the width of the border, which shows that the border is not an inner property of the item, managing its children and descendants, but it's an outer property, since it positions the item in its outer context (i.e., the page in this case).

Comment: what happens if box-sizing is border-box? wouldn't the border be pulled inwards?

Comment: @CristianoMoraes whenever the border manages the inner content of the elements, it acts as an inner border. Whenever it manages the item's position in its outer context, it's an outer border. inner and outer are relative concepts, denoting what the property is affecting. If the attribute is affecting the item's inner content, then it's an inner attribute. If it affects the relation of the item with its outer context, then it's an outer attribute.

Comment: I think I understand. "When position is set to absolute or fixed, the top property specifies the distance between the element's outer margin of top edge and the inner border of the top edge of its containing block." In this case, what would the inner border be and why?

Comment: @CristianoMoraes In this case `border` is an outer property, while `padding` acts as an inner border. We can consider it to be the inner border (and we could consider similarly the margin of the children), but I have never heard anyone referring to it like that. So, I would say that in this case there is no inner border, while `border` is an outer property. The reason for this kind of wording would be to be consistent with the technical terms.

Comment: yes, but why would the padding be the "inner border"?

Comment: @CristianoMoraes the reason why one could consider it to be an inner border is that 1. It is an inner property and 2. Separates the frontier of the item from the contents by the specified amount. Yet, I do not consider it to be an inner border, because that would be inconsistent with the name of this attribute. If this answer clarified matters, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: so the top property would be this distance? https://imgur.com/a/mruIJQU

Comment: @CristianoMoraes It's between the margin edge of the inner item and the content edge of the outer item.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the distance between the inner border (in this case, padding edge, as you said above) of the containing block? "When position is set to absolute or fixed, the top property specifies the distance between the element's outer margin of top edge and the inner border of the top edge of its containing block"

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer the question at all. Somewhere in your comments might be the answer but that's not where it belongs. You could remove everything in your answer and post some of your comments and possibly supply the real answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
For this image from https://www.w3.org/TR/css-box-3/, `outer margin` = `margin edge/outer edge` and `inner border` = `padding edge`.

inner margin = outer border = border edge
inner border = outer padding = padding edge